# Labeling ParentNode - Protovis Treemap

Tags: javascript, treemap, protovis

I'm trying to label the parent node's of the treemap, but so far have only been able to successfully access the individual leaves of the treemap. Right now it does print the names of the parent nodes, but i want it to center on the parentnode, not the individual leaf as I have it now.

```
 json = {"sectors":{"Beer":{"Coors Light":77,"The Coors Light Brewing Company":61,"Coors Banquet":31,"Miller Lite":30},"Media":{"Disney Movies":91,"Disney":90,"CBSSports.com":87,"FOX Broadcasting":85,"ABC News":85,"Netflix":74,"Fox News":70,"CBS Home Entertainment":70,"FOX Sports":68,"ESPN":68,"DISH Network":68,"ABC 20/20":64,"Walt Disney Animation Studios":62,"ABC Family":58,"XFINITY":56,"Disney Pixar":49,"SportsCenter":35,"DirecTV":28,"Disneyland":25,"CBS":17,"ABC Family\u2019s 25 Days of Christmas":16,"Walt Disney World":15,"CBS News":12,"Fox Searchlight Pictures":11,"20th Century Fox":5},"Delivery":{"USPS Stamps":96,"UPS":86,"FedEx":75,"U.S. Postal Service":46,"I am FedEx":20},"Finance":{"Chase Freedom":99,"Capital One":98,"Chase Community Giving":86,"Wells Fargo":72,"J.P. Morgan Corporate Challenge: Boston":70,"J.P. Morgan Community":69,"Citi":68,"Chase Blueprint":63,"E*TRADE Financial":50,"Building Opportunity from Bank of America":31,"Small Business Saturday":21,"J.P. Morgan Corporate Challenge":15,"Fidelity Investments":1},"Automotive":{"Cadillac":98,"Lincoln":93,"Toyota 4Runner":93,"Ford Focus":87,"Chevrolet":87,"Toyota Prius":81,"Honda Insight":81,"Ford Electric Vehicles":77,"Dodge":75,"VW Passat":74,"Honda CR-Z":73,"Toyota USA":72,"BMW USA":72,"Mercedes-Benz USA":70,"VW Beetle":70,"Ford Fiesta":69,"VW Eos":68,"Chevrolet Volt":68,"Toyota Sienna":66,"Team Chevy":63,"Dodge Viper":60,"Ford Motor Company":58,"Acura":56,"Dodge Challenger":53,"Infiniti":51,"Ford Explorer":51,"Nissan":51,"Mercedes-Benz":49,"Ford Taurus":43,"BMW":43,"VW Jetta":42,"Jeep":38,"Toyota Yaris":37,"GMC":36,"Ford Trucks":36,"Ford Mustang":35,"Mazda":34,"VW USA":33,"Lexus":32,"Honda Civic":30,"Subaru of America, Inc.":26,"Ford Fusion + Hybrid":22,"Kia Motors America":18,"Audi R8":16,"Ford Ranger":14,"Honda":14,"Chrysler":13,"VW CC":10,"VW Routan":9,"VW GTI":5,"Ram":4,"Buick":0},"Food":{"Dr Pepper":95,"Campbell's Kitchen":66,"Kraft Foods - Recipes and Tips":66,"Dannon Light & Fit":54,"Pepsi Max":53,"Diet Pepsi":45,"Cheerios":42,"Diet Coke":32,"Coca-Cola Zero":23,"Pepsi":21,"PepsiCo":21,"Yoplait":20,"Coca-Cola":11,"Yoplait Smoothie":9,"Gatorade":0,"Pillsbury Baking":0,"Pillsbury":0},"Other":{"Pella Windows and Doors":80,"Bowflex":69,"BP America":68,"Liberty Travel":67,"Sinceramente Hallmark":51,"Thank You, Mom by P&G":43,"AARP":42,"your GREETING CARD COMPETITION brought to you by Hallmark Cards":32,"Procter & Gamble":31,"Pro Plan":29,"Hallmark":23,"P&G Everyday Solutions":17,"Bridgestone Tires":16,"Purina ONE":16,"Southwest Airlines":4,"Purina Cat Chow":4,"H&R Block ":3},"Personal Care":{"Maybelline New York":58,"CoverGirl":53,"Axe Angels club":53,"Revlon":21,"AXE ":0},"Insurance":{"Travelers Insurance":87,"State Farm Insurance":82,"Careers at Allstate":79,"Mayhem":78,"Farmers Insurance":71,"Allstate Insurance":64,"GEICO Motorcycle":62,"GEICO RV":50,"GEICO Careers":48,"Progressive ":42,"Liberty Mutual":41,"Nationwide Insurance":41,"Esurance":26,"GEICO":22,"GEICO Caveman":21,"GEICO Kash":20,"The GEICO Gecko":16,"State Farm Careers":15,"Allstate Motorcycle":13,"State Farm Nation":5},"Apparel":{"Nike Sportswear":80,"Nike 6.0":47,"Nike Basketball":42,"Nike Football":38,"Nike":34,"Nike Golf":32,"Nike Running":26,"Nike Women":7,"Nike Baseball":6},"Cleaning":{"Swiffer":99,"Clorox":96,"Lysol":96,"Glade":79,"CloroxConnects":61,"Tide":55,"Febreze":38,"Clorox Clean-Up":5},"Telecom":{"Verizon FiOS":80,"Vonage":80,"T-Mobile USA":69,"Sprint":66,"Verizon Wireless Careers":37,"Verizon Wireless":5},"Education":{"University of Phoenix":4},"Restaurant":{"Taco Bell":90,"Burger King":88,"Wendy's":80,"Dunkin' Donuts":76,"Chili's Grill & Bar":70,"McDonald's":57,"Subway":46,"Pizza Hut":46,"Starbucks":27},"Weight Loss":{"Nutrisystem":34,"Weight Watchers":13},"Drug":{"Pfizer":58},"Retail":{"The Home Depot":90,"Best Buy":86,"Lowe's Home Improvement":81,"Best Buy Music":67,"Amazon.com":66,"Target Baby":62,"Walmart":60,"Best Buy Mobile":54,"Target Style":41,"Best Buy Movies":31,"Macy's":29,"Target":24,"The Scooter Store":19,"Safeway":5},"Electronics":{"BlackBerry":99,"Dell":97,"GE Appliances":96,"Microsoft Outlook":95,"IBM":94,"GE":92,"Microsoft OneNote":91,"Microsoft":90,"BlackBerry for Sprint":86,"Samsung Digital Imaging":85,"Time Warner":84,"Microsoft Tag":84,"Samsung Televisions":79,"Microsoft Visual Studio":72,"NBC Olympics":71,"Samsung Mobile USA":71,"Sony Electronics":66,"Samsung USA":65,"Samsung Service":63,"LG USA Mobile":61,"Sony PlayStation":60,"LG Electronics USA":58,"Microsoft Publisher":57,"NBC":57,"Microsoft Office":56,"Samsung Galaxy Tab":56,"Microsoft PowerPoint":54,"Time Warner Cable":50,"Samsung Notebook":48,"Dell Spot":47,"Microsoft Web Platform":46,"Canon":45,"Samsung Apps":44,"Dell Go Green":36,"Samsung Galaxy S":32,"Microsoft Access":32,"Microsoft Visio":26,"Microsoft Excel":25,"BlackBerry for AT&T":24,"IBM Research":23,"LG-Ericsson USA":20,"Sony":20,"Microsoft Word":17,"Microsoft Learning":14,"Microsoft Windows Server":11,"Microsoft Lync":11,"Dell Deals":7,"HP":2,"Dell Outlet":0}},"ids":{"Coors Light":300005,"The Coors Light Brewing Company":300007,"Coors Banquet":300006,"Miller Lite":280745,"Disney Movies":299960,"Disney":299957,"CBSSports.com":299977,"FOX Broadcasting":299966,"ABC News":299971,"Netflix":272975,"Fox News":299963,"CBS Home Entertainment":299976,"FOX Sports":299965,"ESPN":299968,"DISH Network":299955,"ABC 20/20":299973,"Walt Disney Animation Studios":299962,"ABC Family":299970,"XFINITY":299956,"Disney Pixar":299959,"SportsCenter":299969,"DirecTV":299954,"Disneyland":299958,"CBS":299974,"ABC Family\u2019s 25 Days of Christmas":299972,"Walt Disney World":299961,"CBS News":299975,"Fox Searchlight Pictures":299964,"20th Century Fox":299967,"USPS Stamps":300012,"UPS":300010,"FedEx":300008,"U.S. Postal Service":300011,"I am FedEx":300009,"Chase Freedom":296680,"Capital One":296679,"Chase Community Giving":296253,"Wells Fargo":296249,"J.P. Morgan Corporate Challenge: Boston":296678,"J.P. Morgan Community":296258,"Citi":296248,"Chase Blueprint":296257,"E*TRADE Financial":268920,"Building Opportunity from Bank of America":296254,"Small Business Saturday":299930,"J.P. Morgan Corporate Challenge":296677,"Fidelity Investments":296103,"Cadillac":235989,"Lincoln":235985,"Toyota 4Runner":263153,"Ford Focus":235416,"Chevrolet":235410,"Toyota Prius":263165,"Honda Insight":235343,"Ford Electric Vehicles":279420,"Dodge":235891,"VW Passat":235942,"Honda CR-Z":269590,"Toyota USA":235417,"BMW USA":234256,"Mercedes-Benz USA":269302,"VW Beetle":235911,"Ford Fiesta":235415,"VW Eos":235941,"Chevrolet Volt":235409,"Toyota Sienna":263154,"Team Chevy":300043,"Dodge Viper":252252,"Ford Motor Company":235411,"Acura":234261,"Dodge Challenger":252251,"Infiniti":234266,"Ford Explorer":279418,"Nissan":234267,"Mercedes-Benz":234258,"Ford Taurus":279419,"BMW":234251,"VW Jetta":235946,"Jeep":235892,"Toyota Yaris":235421,"GMC":235987,"Ford Trucks":235414,"Ford Mustang":235412,"Mazda":299866,"VW USA":235947,"Lexus":235267,"Honda Civic":235341,"Subaru of America, Inc.":235344,"Ford Fusion + Hybrid":263026,"Kia Motors America":235949,"Audi R8":235922,"Ford Ranger":279421,"Honda":235340,"Chrysler":235988,"VW CC":235945,"VW Routan":235944,"VW GTI":235943,"Ram":252250,"Buick":299865,"Dr Pepper":289234,"Campbell's Kitchen":293375,"Kraft Foods - Recipes and Tips":236532,"Dannon Light & Fit":255741,"Pepsi Max":280650,"Diet Pepsi":289233,"Cheerios":293370,"Diet Coke":289235,"Coca-Cola Zero":289238,"Pepsi":273002,"PepsiCo":280738,"Yoplait":293945,"Coca-Cola":289229,"Yoplait Smoothie":293946,"Gatorade":243071,"Pillsbury Baking":293372,"Pillsbury":293368,"Pella Windows and Doors":300037,"Bowflex":300032,"BP America":300030,"Liberty Travel":300036,"Sinceramente Hallmark":285603,"Thank You, Mom by P&G":300040,"AARP":300029,"your GREETING CARD COMPETITION brought to you by Hallmark Cards":285547,"Procter & Gamble":300038,"Pro Plan":300035,"Hallmark":285219,"P&G Everyday Solutions":300039,"Bridgestone Tires":300041,"Purina ONE":300033,"Southwest Airlines":300028,"Purina Cat Chow":300034,"H&R Block ":300031,"Maybelline New York":256088,"CoverGirl":256087,"Axe Angels club":242965,"Revlon":256093,"AXE ":242957,"Travelers Insurance":241056,"State Farm Insurance":237669,"Careers at Allstate":296694,"Mayhem":296695,"Farmers Insurance":270396,"Allstate Insurance":237667,"GEICO Motorcycle":290103,"GEICO RV":290099,"GEICO Careers":244667,"Progressive ":240858,"Liberty Mutual":240862,"Nationwide Insurance":237668,"Esurance":240861,"GEICO":237671,"GEICO Caveman":290100,"GEICO Kash":290102,"The GEICO Gecko":237672,"State Farm Careers":244668,"Allstate Motorcycle":296693,"State Farm Nation":277522,"Nike Sportswear":287251,"Nike 6.0":287249,"Nike Basketball":287254,"Nike Football":287252,"Nike":287248,"Nike Golf":259273,"Nike Running":287250,"Nike Women":260392,"Nike Baseball":287253,"Swiffer":300003,"Clorox":299998,"Lysol":300004,"Glade":300001,"CloroxConnects":300000,"Tide":299997,"Febreze":300002,"Clorox Clean-Up":299999,"Verizon FiOS":237830,"Vonage":293315,"T-Mobile USA":237832,"Sprint":237835,"Verizon Wireless Careers":237831,"Verizon Wireless":237829,"University of Phoenix":277367,"Taco Bell":293332,"Burger King":293330,"Wendy's":293943,"Dunkin' Donuts":279338,"Chili's Grill & Bar":299890,"McDonald's":293331,"Subway":273659,"Pizza Hut":293400,"Starbucks":277858,"Nutrisystem":270685,"Weight Watchers":263087,"Pfizer":257351,"The Home Depot":290087,"Best Buy":290089,"Lowe's Home Improvement":290088,"Best Buy Music":290090,"Amazon.com":293412,"Target Baby":290082,"Walmart":290085,"Best Buy Mobile":290091,"Target Style":290083,"Best Buy Movies":290093,"Macy's":290096,"Target":290081,"The Scooter Store":300054,"Safeway":296038,"BlackBerry":237821,"Dell":236264,"GE Appliances":288918,"Microsoft Outlook":277495,"IBM":292839,"GE":299950,"Microsoft OneNote":277493,"Microsoft":234136,"BlackBerry for Sprint":237884,"Samsung Digital Imaging":263317,"Time Warner":266908,"Microsoft Tag":277494,"Samsung Televisions":288921,"Microsoft Visual Studio":234168,"NBC Olympics":266564,"Samsung Mobile USA":294087,"Sony Electronics":263313,"Samsung USA":263316,"Samsung Service":288922,"LG USA Mobile":289167,"Sony PlayStation":236075,"LG Electronics USA":288915,"Microsoft Publisher":277505,"NBC":266563,"Microsoft Office":234169,"Samsung Galaxy Tab":294086,"Microsoft PowerPoint":277497,"Time Warner Cable":266909,"Samsung Notebook":289021,"Dell Spot":236265,"Microsoft Web Platform":277504,"Canon":299953,"Samsung Apps":289022,"Dell Go Green":236267,"Samsung Galaxy S":294883,"Microsoft Access":277500,"Microsoft Visio":277498,"Microsoft Excel":277506,"BlackBerry for AT&T":237824,"IBM Research":292838,"LG-Ericsson USA":288916,"Sony":263312,"Microsoft Word":277496,"Microsoft Learning":277503,"Microsoft Windows Server":277501,"Microsoft Lync":277502,"Dell Deals":236268,"HP":292840,"Dell Outlet":236270},"eranks":[{"sector":"Beer","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Coors Light","id":300005,"score":77},{"brand":"The Coors Light Brewing Company","id":300007,"score":61},{"brand":"Coors Banquet","id":300006,"score":31},{"brand":"Miller Lite","id":280745,"score":30}]},{"sector":"Media","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Disney Movies","id":299960,"score":91},{"brand":"Disney","id":299957,"score":90},{"brand":"CBSSports.com","id":299977,"score":87},{"brand":"FOX Broadcasting","id":299966,"score":85},{"brand":"ABC News","id":299971,"score":85},{"brand":"Netflix","id":272975,"score":74},{"brand":"Fox News","id":299963,"score":70},{"brand":"CBS Home Entertainment","id":299976,"score":70},{"brand":"FOX Sports","id":299965,"score":68},{"brand":"ESPN","id":299968,"score":68},{"brand":"DISH Network","id":299955,"score":68},{"brand":"ABC 20/20","id":299973,"score":64},{"brand":"Walt Disney Animation Studios","id":299962,"score":62},{"brand":"ABC Family","id":299970,"score":58},{"brand":"XFINITY","id":299956,"score":56},{"brand":"Disney Pixar","id":299959,"score":49},{"brand":"SportsCenter","id":299969,"score":35},{"brand":"DirecTV","id":299954,"score":28},{"brand":"Disneyland","id":299958,"score":25},{"brand":"CBS","id":299974,"score":17},{"brand":"ABC Family\u2019s 25 Days of Christmas","id":299972,"score":16},{"brand":"Walt Disney World","id":299961,"score":15},{"brand":"CBS News","id":299975,"score":12},{"brand":"Fox Searchlight Pictures","id":299964,"score":11},{"brand":"20th Century Fox","id":299967,"score":5}]},{"sector":"Delivery","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"USPS Stamps","id":300012,"score":96},{"brand":"UPS","id":300010,"score":86},{"brand":"FedEx","id":300008,"score":75},{"brand":"U.S. Postal Service","id":300011,"score":46},{"brand":"I am FedEx","id":300009,"score":20}]},{"sector":"Finance","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Chase Freedom","id":296680,"score":99},{"brand":"Capital One","id":296679,"score":98},{"brand":"Chase Community Giving","id":296253,"score":86},{"brand":"Wells Fargo","id":296249,"score":72},{"brand":"J.P. Morgan Corporate Challenge: Boston","id":296678,"score":70},{"brand":"J.P. Morgan Community","id":296258,"score":69},{"brand":"Citi","id":296248,"score":68},{"brand":"Chase Blueprint","id":296257,"score":63},{"brand":"E*TRADE Financial","id":268920,"score":50},{"brand":"Building Opportunity from Bank of America","id":296254,"score":31},{"brand":"Small Business Saturday","id":299930,"score":21},{"brand":"J.P. Morgan Corporate Challenge","id":296677,"score":15},{"brand":"Fidelity Investments","id":296103,"score":1}]},{"sector":"Automotive","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Cadillac","id":235989,"score":98},{"brand":"Lincoln","id":235985,"score":93},{"brand":"Toyota 4Runner","id":263153,"score":93},{"brand":"Ford Focus","id":235416,"score":87},{"brand":"Chevrolet","id":235410,"score":87},{"brand":"Toyota Prius","id":263165,"score":81},{"brand":"Honda Insight","id":235343,"score":81},{"brand":"Ford Electric Vehicles","id":279420,"score":77},{"brand":"Dodge","id":235891,"score":75},{"brand":"VW Passat","id":235942,"score":74},{"brand":"Honda CR-Z","id":269590,"score":73},{"brand":"Toyota USA","id":235417,"score":72},{"brand":"BMW USA","id":234256,"score":72},{"brand":"Mercedes-Benz USA","id":269302,"score":70},{"brand":"VW Beetle","id":235911,"score":70},{"brand":"Ford Fiesta","id":235415,"score":69},{"brand":"VW Eos","id":235941,"score":68},{"brand":"Chevrolet Volt","id":235409,"score":68},{"brand":"Toyota Sienna","id":263154,"score":66},{"brand":"Team Chevy","id":300043,"score":63},{"brand":"Dodge Viper","id":252252,"score":60},{"brand":"Ford Motor Company","id":235411,"score":58},{"brand":"Acura","id":234261,"score":56},{"brand":"Dodge Challenger","id":252251,"score":53},{"brand":"Infiniti","id":234266,"score":51},{"brand":"Ford Explorer","id":279418,"score":51},{"brand":"Nissan","id":234267,"score":51},{"brand":"Mercedes-Benz","id":234258,"score":49},{"brand":"Ford Taurus","id":279419,"score":43},{"brand":"BMW","id":234251,"score":43},{"brand":"VW Jetta","id":235946,"score":42},{"brand":"Jeep","id":235892,"score":38},{"brand":"Toyota Yaris","id":235421,"score":37},{"brand":"GMC","id":235987,"score":36},{"brand":"Ford Trucks","id":235414,"score":36},{"brand":"Ford Mustang","id":235412,"score":35},{"brand":"Mazda","id":299866,"score":34},{"brand":"VW USA","id":235947,"score":33},{"brand":"Lexus","id":235267,"score":32},{"brand":"Honda Civic","id":235341,"score":30},{"brand":"Subaru of America, Inc.","id":235344,"score":26},{"brand":"Ford Fusion + Hybrid","id":263026,"score":22},{"brand":"Kia Motors America","id":235949,"score":18},{"brand":"Audi R8","id":235922,"score":16},{"brand":"Ford Ranger","id":279421,"score":14},{"brand":"Honda","id":235340,"score":14},{"brand":"Chrysler","id":235988,"score":13},{"brand":"VW CC","id":235945,"score":10},{"brand":"VW Routan","id":235944,"score":9},{"brand":"VW GTI","id":235943,"score":5},{"brand":"Ram","id":252250,"score":4},{"brand":"Buick","id":299865,"score":0}]},{"sector":"Food","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Dr Pepper","id":289234,"score":95},{"brand":"Campbell's Kitchen","id":293375,"score":66},{"brand":"Kraft Foods - Recipes and Tips","id":236532,"score":66},{"brand":"Dannon Light & Fit","id":255741,"score":54},{"brand":"Pepsi Max","id":280650,"score":53},{"brand":"Diet Pepsi","id":289233,"score":45},{"brand":"Cheerios","id":293370,"score":42},{"brand":"Diet Coke","id":289235,"score":32},{"brand":"Coca-Cola Zero","id":289238,"score":23},{"brand":"Pepsi","id":273002,"score":21},{"brand":"PepsiCo","id":280738,"score":21},{"brand":"Yoplait","id":293945,"score":20},{"brand":"Coca-Cola","id":289229,"score":11},{"brand":"Yoplait Smoothie","id":293946,"score":9},{"brand":"Gatorade","id":243071,"score":0},{"brand":"Pillsbury Baking","id":293372,"score":0},{"brand":"Pillsbury","id":293368,"score":0}]},{"sector":"Other","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Pella Windows and Doors","id":300037,"score":80},{"brand":"Bowflex","id":300032,"score":69},{"brand":"BP America","id":300030,"score":68},{"brand":"Liberty Travel","id":300036,"score":67},{"brand":"Sinceramente Hallmark","id":285603,"score":51},{"brand":"Thank You, Mom by P&G","id":300040,"score":43},{"brand":"AARP","id":300029,"score":42},{"brand":"your GREETING CARD COMPETITION brought to you by Hallmark Cards","id":285547,"score":32},{"brand":"Procter & Gamble","id":300038,"score":31},{"brand":"Pro Plan","id":300035,"score":29},{"brand":"Hallmark","id":285219,"score":23},{"brand":"P&G Everyday Solutions","id":300039,"score":17},{"brand":"Bridgestone Tires","id":300041,"score":16},{"brand":"Purina ONE","id":300033,"score":16},{"brand":"Southwest Airlines","id":300028,"score":4},{"brand":"Purina Cat Chow","id":300034,"score":4},{"brand":"H&R Block ","id":300031,"score":3}]},{"sector":"Personal Care","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Maybelline New York","id":256088,"score":58},{"brand":"CoverGirl","id":256087,"score":53},{"brand":"Axe Angels club","id":242965,"score":53},{"brand":"Revlon","id":256093,"score":21},{"brand":"AXE ","id":242957,"score":0}]},{"sector":"Insurance","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Travelers Insurance","id":241056,"score":87},{"brand":"State Farm Insurance","id":237669,"score":82},{"brand":"Careers at Allstate","id":296694,"score":79},{"brand":"Mayhem","id":296695,"score":78},{"brand":"Farmers Insurance","id":270396,"score":71},{"brand":"Allstate Insurance","id":237667,"score":64},{"brand":"GEICO Motorcycle","id":290103,"score":62},{"brand":"GEICO RV","id":290099,"score":50},{"brand":"GEICO Careers","id":244667,"score":48},{"brand":"Progressive ","id":240858,"score":42},{"brand":"Liberty Mutual","id":240862,"score":41},{"brand":"Nationwide Insurance","id":237668,"score":41},{"brand":"Esurance","id":240861,"score":26},{"brand":"GEICO","id":237671,"score":22},{"brand":"GEICO Caveman","id":290100,"score":21},{"brand":"GEICO Kash","id":290102,"score":20},{"brand":"The GEICO Gecko","id":237672,"score":16},{"brand":"State Farm Careers","id":244668,"score":15},{"brand":"Allstate Motorcycle","id":296693,"score":13},{"brand":"State Farm Nation","id":277522,"score":5}]},{"sector":"Apparel","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Nike Sportswear","id":287251,"score":80},{"brand":"Nike 6.0","id":287249,"score":47},{"brand":"Nike Basketball","id":287254,"score":42},{"brand":"Nike Football","id":287252,"score":38},{"brand":"Nike","id":287248,"score":34},{"brand":"Nike Golf","id":259273,"score":32},{"brand":"Nike Running","id":287250,"score":26},{"brand":"Nike Women","id":260392,"score":7},{"brand":"Nike Baseball","id":287253,"score":6}]},{"sector":"Cleaning","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Swiffer","id":300003,"score":99},{"brand":"Clorox","id":299998,"score":96},{"brand":"Lysol","id":300004,"score":96},{"brand":"Glade","id":300001,"score":79},{"brand":"CloroxConnects","id":300000,"score":61},{"brand":"Tide","id":299997,"score":55},{"brand":"Febreze","id":300002,"score":38},{"brand":"Clorox Clean-Up","id":299999,"score":5}]},{"sector":"Telecom","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Verizon FiOS","id":237830,"score":80},{"brand":"Vonage","id":293315,"score":80},{"brand":"T-Mobile USA","id":237832,"score":69},{"brand":"Sprint","id":237835,"score":66},{"brand":"Verizon Wireless Careers","id":237831,"score":37},{"brand":"Verizon Wireless","id":237829,"score":5}]},{"sector":"Education","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"University of Phoenix","id":277367,"score":4}]},{"sector":"Restaurant","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Taco Bell","id":293332,"score":90},{"brand":"Burger King","id":293330,"score":88},{"brand":"Wendy's","id":293943,"score":80},{"brand":"Dunkin' Donuts","id":279338,"score":76},{"brand":"Chili's Grill & Bar","id":299890,"score":70},{"brand":"McDonald's","id":293331,"score":57},{"brand":"Subway","id":273659,"score":46},{"brand":"Pizza Hut","id":293400,"score":46},{"brand":"Starbucks","id":277858,"score":27}]},{"sector":"Weight Loss","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Nutrisystem","id":270685,"score":34},{"brand":"Weight Watchers","id":263087,"score":13}]},{"sector":"Drug","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"Pfizer","id":257351,"score":58}]},{"sector":"Retail","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"The Home Depot","id":290087,"score":90},{"brand":"Best Buy","id":290089,"score":86},{"brand":"Lowe's Home Improvement","id":290088,"score":81},{"brand":"Best Buy Music","id":290090,"score":67},{"brand":"Amazon.com","id":293412,"score":66},{"brand":"Target Baby","id":290082,"score":62},{"brand":"Walmart","id":290085,"score":60},{"brand":"Best Buy Mobile","id":290091,"score":54},{"brand":"Target Style","id":290083,"score":41},{"brand":"Best Buy Movies","id":290093,"score":31},{"brand":"Macy's","id":290096,"score":29},{"brand":"Target","id":290081,"score":24},{"brand":"The Scooter Store","id":300054,"score":19},{"brand":"Safeway","id":296038,"score":5}]},{"sector":"Electronics","score":0,"pages":[{"brand":"BlackBerry","id":237821,"score":99},{"brand":"Dell","id":236264,"score":97},{"brand":"GE Appliances","id":288918,"score":96},{"brand":"Microsoft Outlook","id":277495,"score":95},{"brand":"IBM","id":292839,"score":94},{"brand":"GE","id":299950,"score":92},{"brand":"Microsoft OneNote","id":277493,"score":91},{"brand":"Microsoft","id":234136,"score":90},{"brand":"BlackBerry for Sprint","id":237884,"score":86},{"brand":"Samsung Digital Imaging","id":263317,"score":85},{"brand":"Time Warner","id":266908,"score":84},{"brand":"Microsoft Tag","id":277494,"score":84},{"brand":"Samsung Televisions","id":288921,"score":79},{"brand":"Microsoft Visual Studio","id":234168,"score":72},{"brand":"NBC Olympics","id":266564,"score":71},{"brand":"Samsung Mobile USA","id":294087,"score":71},{"brand":"Sony Electronics","id":263313,"score":66},{"brand":"Samsung USA","id":263316,"score":65},{"brand":"Samsung Service","id":288922,"score":63},{"brand":"LG USA Mobile","id":289167,"score":61},{"brand":"Sony PlayStation","id":236075,"score":60},{"brand":"LG Electronics USA","id":288915,"score":58},{"brand":"Microsoft Publisher","id":277505,"score":57},{"brand":"NBC","id":266563,"score":57},{"brand":"Microsoft Office","id":234169,"score":56},{"brand":"Samsung Galaxy Tab","id":294086,"score":56},{"brand":"Microsoft PowerPoint","id":277497,"score":54},{"brand":"Time Warner Cable","id":266909,"score":50},{"brand":"Samsung Notebook","id":289021,"score":48},{"brand":"Dell Spot","id":236265,"score":47},{"brand":"Microsoft Web Platform","id":277504,"score":46},{"brand":"Canon","id":299953,"score":45},{"brand":"Samsung Apps","id":289022,"score":44},{"brand":"Dell Go Green","id":236267,"score":36},{"brand":"Samsung Galaxy S","id":294883,"score":32},{"brand":"Microsoft Access","id":277500,"score":32},{"brand":"Microsoft Visio","id":277498,"score":26},{"brand":"Microsoft Excel","id":277506,"score":25},{"brand":"BlackBerry for AT&T","id":237824,"score":24},{"brand":"IBM Research","id":292838,"score":23},{"brand":"LG-Ericsson USA","id":288916,"score":20},{"brand":"Sony","id":263312,"score":20},{"brand":"Microsoft Word","id":277496,"score":17},{"brand":"Microsoft Learning","id":277503,"score":14},{"brand":"Microsoft Windows Server","id":277501,"score":11},{"brand":"Microsoft Lync","id":277502,"score":11},{"brand":"Dell Deals","id":236268,"score":7},{"brand":"HP","id":292840,"score":2},{"brand":"Dell Outlet","id":236270,"score":0}]}]};

var tree = json.sectors;
var ids = json.ids;
arr=[];
sRank={};
function active(d, v) {
            d.active = v; 
            if (d.parentNode) {
                active(d.parentNode, v);
                }
}

// used for alpha
sRank={};
for(var i in json.eranks)
{
    var sector = json.eranks[i].sector;
    sRank[sector]=[];
    for(var p in json.eranks[i].pages){
        sRank[sector].push(json.eranks[i].pages[p].brand)
    }
}
        var nodes = pv.dom(tree).root("tree").nodes();
        color = pv.Colors.category20().by(function (d) { return d.parentNode.nodeName });


        var vis = new pv.Panel()
                 .width(660)
                 .height(900);

        var treemap = vis.add(pv.Layout.Treemap)
                 .nodes(nodes);



        treemap.leaf.add(pv.Panel)
                 .fillStyle(function (d) { return color(d).alpha(1-sRank[d.parentNode.nodeName].indexOf(d.nodeName)/sRank[d.parentNode.nodeName].length) })
                 .strokeStyle("#fff")
                 .lineWidth(1)
                 .antialias(false)
                 .cursor("pointer")                  
                 .title(function(d) { return d.nodeName})
                 .event("click", function (d) {alert(d.parentNode.nodeName); });


       treemap.leaf.add(pv.Label)
            .font("20px sans-serif")
            .textBaseline("bottom")
            .text(function(d) { middle=Math.round(sRank[d.parentNode.nodeName].length/2)-1; 
            if(sRank[d.parentNode.nodeName].indexOf(d.nodeName) == middle) 
                {return d.parentNode.nodeName}}
            );

        vis.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option here is to use `treemap.label`, which is automatically centered for each node. By default, `treemap.label` has the `.visible` property set like this:

```
.visible(function(n) { return !n.firstChild; })
```

which only shows the label for leaf nodes. However, you can set the `.visible` property yourself once you've added a treemap, and change it to show only parent nodes (you have to make sure they have a parent node as well, or you get an extra, unwanted label for the root node):

```
treemap.label
    .visible(function(d) { return d.firstChild && d.parentNode });
```

In your example, you can chain this to your label, so the full snippet would look like:

```
treemap.label
    .visible(function(d) { return d.firstChild && d.parentNode })
  .add(pv.Label)
    .font("20px sans-serif")
    .textBaseline("bottom")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.nodeName
    });
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/T3fnT/1/

Comment: Sure! I don't think the `treemap.label` visibility is documented anywhere - had to look through the source to find it.